# git diff hexsha:directorypath/file

Tags: python, git, gitpython

Given that `hexsha`, `directory` and `file` are known, how can I get the diff between 2 specific files, for example the following will return the diff between 2 revisions:

```
irepo.git.diff("93ba8ae12f79e7f90e5ec5217e44ce28624a66d8..d144da4b5f0dff89b918bc88629cb7902150d77c")
```

But, how can I produce the diff of `<directory>/<file>` included in both revisions above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GitPython's built-in diff facilities to do that.

```
import git
r = git.Repo(path_to_repo)
diff_index = r.commit(lhs_hexsha).diff(rhs_hexsha, create_patch=True)
# find all modified paths you are interested in
for diff_info in diff_index.iter_change_type('M'):
    if diff_info.a_blob.path == my_path:
        print(str(diff_info))
```

Follow the links for more information on [diffing objects](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/tutorial.html#obtaining-diff-information), the [`diff()` call](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=diff#git.diff.Diffable.diff), the returned [`DiffIndex` object](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=diff#git.diff.DiffIndex), or the [`Diff` objects](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=diff#git.diff.Diff) contained therein.

The `a_blob` referenced in the example is a [`Blob`](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=blob#module-git.objects.blob) object, which provides read-access to the compared file at the commit at `lhs_hexsha`. There is a `b_blob` too which represents the state of the file at the commit at `rhs_hexsha`.

Comment: : thanks Byron. would you be so kind please to describe with simple words what "a_blob" is ?